How to transform this combination of $ _2F_1 $?
Following my previous question How to transform this MeijerG $G_{3,3}^{2,3}$ into a hypergeometric function $ _2F_1 $, I transformed a MeijerG function $G_{3,3}^{2,3}$ below into a combination of hypergeometric function $ _2F_1 $
 y = y = MeijerG[{{(1 - k)/2, 2 - k/2, -(k/2)}, {}}, {{0, 1/2}, {(1 - k)/2}}, (k - z)/z, 1/2]
 FunctionExpand[y] // FullSimplify

(* Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Gamma[-1 + \[Kappa]/2] Gamma[1 + \[Kappa]/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-2 + \[Kappa]), (2 + \[Kappa])/2, 1/2, (z - \[Kappa])^2/z^2] + (2 Gamma[1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa])] Gamma[(3 + \[Kappa])/2] (\[Kappa] (-2 z + \[Kappa]) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa]), (3 + \[Kappa])/2, -(1/2), (z - \[Kappa])^2/z^2] - (-4 z \[Kappa] (1 + \[Kappa]) + 2 \[Kappa]^2 (1 + \[Kappa]) + z^2 (1 + 2 \[Kappa])) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa]), (3 + \[Kappa])/2, 1/2, (z - \[Kappa])^2/z^2]))/(z (z - \[Kappa]) (-4 + \[Kappa]^2)))  *) 

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{\pi}}=g_1+\frac{2\kappa  (\kappa -2 z)}{\left(\kappa ^2-4\right) z (z-\kappa )}g_2 -\frac{2 \left(2 \kappa ^2 (\kappa +1)+(2 \kappa +1) z^2-4 \kappa  (\kappa +1) z\right)}{\left(\kappa ^2-4\right) z (z-\kappa )}g_3,\\
g_1=\Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa -2 }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa +1 }{2}\right)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{\kappa -2}{2},\frac{\kappa +2}{2};\frac{1}{2};u\right),\\
g_2=\Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa -1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa +3}{2}\right)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{\kappa -1}{2},\frac{\kappa +3}{2};-\frac{1}{2};u\right),\\
g_3=\Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa -1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\kappa +3}{2}\right)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{\kappa -1}{2},\frac{\kappa +3}{2};\frac{1}{2};u\right),\\
u=\frac{(z-\kappa )^2}{z^2}.$$
Now I want to transform this combination of $ _2F_1 $ functions into a single $ _2F_1 $
function?
Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Gamma[-1 + \[Kappa]/2] Gamma[1 + \[Kappa]/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-2 + \[Kappa]), (2 + \[Kappa])/2, 1/2, (z - \[Kappa])^2/z^2] + (2 Gamma[1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa])] Gamma[(3 + \[Kappa])/2] (\[Kappa] (-2 z + \[Kappa]) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa]), (3 + \[Kappa])/2, -(1/2), (z - \[Kappa])^2/z^2] - (-4 z \[Kappa] (1 + \[Kappa]) + 
     2 \[Kappa]^2 (1 + \[Kappa]) + z^2 (1 + 2 \[Kappa])) Hypergeometric2F1[
    1/2 (-1 + \[Kappa]), (3 + \[Kappa])/2, 1/2, (z - \[Kappa])^2/
    z^2]))/(z (z - \[Kappa]) (-4 + \[Kappa]^2)))

Can you do this please?

You seems to be confident that such transformation is possible. Are there any hints on why it might be feasible. Do you have some transformation in mind?

@yarchik
according to one of the equations (15)  from Abramowitz and Stegun's Handbook, I think it's possible

The problem is that in the book all formulas for $F(a, b, c, x)$ increment or decrement $a$, $b$, or $c$ by $\pm1$. In your example the increment is $\pm1/2$.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

y[k_, z_] = 
  MeijerG[{{(1 - k)/2, 2 - k/2, -(k/2)}, {}}, {{0, 
       1/2}, {(1 - k)/2}}, (k - z)/z, 1/2] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify;

Using approach provided by Mariusz Iwaniuk
y2[k_, z_] = 
 System`MeijerGDump`MeijerGToSums[
    MeijerG[{{(1 - k)/2, 2 - k/2, -(k/2)}, {}}, {{0, 
       1/2}, {(1 - k)/2}}, (k - z)/z, 1/2], j] // ReleaseHold // FullSimplify

(* Sqrt[π] (Gamma[-1 + k/2] Gamma[1 + k/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-2 + k), (
     2 + k)/2, 1/2, (k - z)^2/z^2] + (1/z)
   2 (-k + z) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + k)] Gamma[(3 + k)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[
     1/2 (-1 + k), (3 + k)/2, 3/2, (k - z)^2/z^2]) *)

The representations are equivalent
y[k, z] == y2[k, z] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

For {k = 1000, z = 100}, the imaginary part is zero
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 {Im[y[1000, 100]] == 0, Im[y2[1000, 100]] == 0} // N[#, 100] &]

(* {True, True} *)

And the real part is
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 {Re[y[1000, 100]], Re[y2[1000, 100]]} // N[#, 100] & // N]

(* {3.401112093366100*10^1263, 3.401112093366100*10^1263} *)

a large number.

Hi @Bob thank you so much for the solution. Can you please comment on this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/304389/58233 ?

It can be simplifed more.
Using undocumented command:
A = System`MeijerGDump`MeijerGToSums[MeijerG[{{(1 - k)/2, 2 - k/2, -(k/2)}, {}}, {{0, 1/2}, {(1 - k)/2}}, (k - z)/z, 1/2], j]

ReleaseHold[A[[1, 1, 1]]] // FullSimplify (*For: Abs[(k - z)/z] <= 1 *)

(*Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Gamma[-1 + k/2] Gamma[1 + k/2] Hypergeometric2F1[
 1/2 (-2 + k), (2 + k)/2, 1/2, (k - z)^2/z^2] + (
2 (-k + z) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + k)] Gamma[(3 + k)/2]*Hypergeometric2F1[
 1/2 (-1 + k), (3 + k)/2, 3/2, (k - z)^2/z^2])/z)*)

 ReleaseHold[A[[1, 2, 1]]] // FullSimplify (*For: Abs[(k - z)/z] > 1*)

 (*Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Gamma[-1 + k/2] Gamma[1 + k/2] Hypergeometric2F1[
 1/2 (-2 + k), (2 + k)/2, 1/2, (k - z)^2/z^2] + (
 2 (-k + z) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + k)] Gamma[(3 + k)/2] 
 Hypergeometric2F1[
 1/2 (-1 + k), (3 + k)/2, 3/2, (k - z)^2/z^2])/z)*)


It looks like Eq. (5.2.27) of the Abramowitz and Stegun's Handbook.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk Thank you so much, even though I was looking for a single term in 2F1. However a simple numerical application for A[[1, 1, 1]] or A[[1, 2, 1]] for z=100 and k=1000 gives Indeterminate, you don't see a solution?
