Unable to plot $\exp(-a \sqrt{1+x^2})$ for $a>700$
I am trying to plot the function bellow f(x,a) for a = {700,750,1000,2000}
f[x_,a_]:= Exp[-a Sqrt[1+x^2]]/BesselK[2, a]

where BesselK[2,a] is the modified Bessel function of second order.
So for a < 700 I obtain a good plot but for a >= 700 I don't get anything. I deal with similar situations sometimes but I can't find a solution.

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},LogLogPlot[Evaluate[Table[f[x,a], {a, {100, 700, 750, 1000, 2000}}]], 
{x,0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14,10000}},PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]},
PlotLegends ->Placed[LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", "a = 2000"}], {0.91, 0.8}], 
ImageSize -> 500]]

which gives


Error messages:
(*General::munfl: Exp[-750.0006] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.*)

(*General::munfl: Exp[-750.00096] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.*)

(*General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.*)


Also how to show all values of y-axis from 10^-14 to 10^5?
Appreciate your help!

One source of the problem is underflow:
N[BesselK[2, 750]]
(*  0.  *)

N[BesselK[2, 750], $MachinePrecision]
(*  8.724748003877388*10^-328  *)

Here's a function that uses the ability of N[] to adapt precision to compute accurate values.
ClearAll[adaptivePrecisionEvaluate];
adaptivePrecisionEvaluate // Attributes = {HoldAll};
adaptivePrecisionEvaluate[f_[x__?NumericQ]] := 
  With[{p = Precision[{x}]},
   adaptivePrecisionEvaluate[f[x], p]
   ];
adaptivePrecisionEvaluate[f_[x__?NumericQ], prec_] := 
  With[{xx = SetPrecision[{x}, Infinity]},
   With[{fx = N[f @@ xx, N@prec]},
    If[prec === MachinePrecision && $MinMachineNumber <= Abs@fx <= $MaxMachineNumber,
     N[fx], fx]
    ]];

OP's plot:
Block[{(*$MaxExtraPrecision=500,*) f},
 f[x_, a_] := Exp[-a  Sqrt[1 + x^2]]/BesselK[2, a];
 Show[
  LogLogPlot[
    Evaluate[
     Table[
      (* inject a into HoldAll adaptivePrecisionEvaluate[] *)
      With[{a = a}, adaptivePrecisionEvaluate@f[x, a]]
      , {a, {100, 700, 750, 1000, 2000}}]]
    , {x, 1*^-3, 100}
    , PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14, 10^5}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", 
        "a = 2000"}], {0.91, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 500
    (* OP wants more ticks in a comment *)
    , FrameTicks -> {
      {Table[{10.^k, 
         If[EvenQ[k], If[k == 0, 1, Superscript[10, k]], 
          ""]}, {k, -14, 5}],
       Table[{10.^k, ""}, {k, -14, 5}]},
      Automatic
      }
    ]
  ]
 ]



Excellent, Thank you @Michael E2.

Forcing Mathematica to perform numerical calculations with a specified precision rather than machine precision can solve this problem, like
f[x0_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ] := 
 Block[{x = SetPrecision[x0, 10], a = SetPrecision[a0, 10]}, 
  Exp[-a  Sqrt[1 + x^2]]/BesselK[2, a]]

f[8.9, 2000]
(*1.13540*10^-6909*)

LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[f[x, a], {a, {100, 700, 750, 1000, 2000}}]], {x, 
  0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14, 10000}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", 
     "a = 2000"}], {0.91, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 500]


For your request of ticks, since the option Frame -> True is added, we can use option FrameTicks to show the ticks. Here is the code:
LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[f[x, a], {a, {100, 700, 750, 1000, 2000}}]], {x, 
  0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14.5, 10^5.5}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", 
     "a = 2000"}], {0.91, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{10^i, 10^ToString[i]}, {i, -15, 5, 5}], 
    None}, {Automatic, None}}]



Thank you so much @Jie Zhu for the solution. Now, how to show all values of y-axis from 10^-14 to 10^5?

@Gallagher The plot range is already from 10^-14 to 10^5. By changing 10^5 to 10^10 you can see the difference.

But they are not shown on y axis, how can I show them?

@MichaelE2 Since the option Frame -> True is added, the option Ticks doesn't work and   FrameTicks can solve the question.

@Gallagher Updated.

@Jie Zhu thank you again.

Yep, that's what I meant.

@BobHanlon It's a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Perhaps for these huge values of a it is sufficient to only plot  the asymptots
asy=Asymptotic[Exp[-a Sqrt[1 + x^2]]/BesselK[2, a], a -> Infinity]
(*Sqrt[a] E^(a - a Sqrt[1 + x^2]) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]*)

LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[ 
   asy , {a, {100, 700, 750 , 1000, 2000 }}]], {x, 0.001, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14, 10000}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", 
     "a = 2000"}], {0.91, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 500] 



Thank you so much @Ulrich Neumann for you solution. Now, how to show all values of y-axis from 10^-14 to 10^5?

To address this, you can use arbitrary precision arithmetic to handle very small numbers. By setting the precision explicitly, you can ensure that the calculations remain accurate even for large values of $a$.
$$
    f(x, a) = \frac{\exp(-a \sqrt{1 + x^2})}{K_2(a)}
    $$
where $K_2(a)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order 2.
Here’s how you can ensure accurate calculations and plotting:

Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic: Use a higher precision to handle very small values.

Increased Plot Range: Ensure the plot range covers the wide range of values on the $y$``-axis.
 Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
   f[x_, a_] := Exp[-a Sqrt[1 + x^2]]/BesselK[2, a];

   LogLogPlot[
     Evaluate[
       Table[
         f[x, a], 
         {a, {100, 700, 750, 1000, 2000}}
       ]
     ], 
     {x, 0.001, 100}, 
     PlotRange -> {{1/100, 10}, {10^-14, 10000}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["x"]], Text[Style["f"]]},
     PlotLegends -> Placed[
       LineLegend[{"a = 100", "a = 700", "a = 750", "a = 1000", "a = 2000"}], 
       {0.91, 0.8}
     ], 
     ImageSize -> 500, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 50
   ]
 ]





I presume you noticed that your plot looks exactly like the OP's defective plot and is still missing the three plots for a = 750, 1000, and 2000. What's the explanation for why adding WorkingPrecision -> 50 doesn't work?
